# JavaFX ChoiceBox NullPointerException whatever I do

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to add values to a ChoiceBox that exists in my FXML file that I've created with SceneBuilder, but when I try to do that (in the main class), I get a NullPointerException whatever I try. Note that the project successfully runs when I comment out the ChoiceBox code in the `initialize()` method (see below), so there's not another cause for the NPE.

**Some other points:**

- I also get a NPE when I try to do something with the TextField in the same FXML file
- That FXML is a new window that pops up when a certain button is clicked in the parent window (a window to add a new item to the database)

I moved the ChoiceBox code to the `start()` method but that just moved the problem to a different line in the file. Do you have any idea what the cause could be? I would be very grateful because I've already spent two hours on the problem...

**In my FXML file I have**

```
<ChoiceBox fx:id="itemKeuze" layoutX="132.0" layoutY="33.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
```

**In my main class I have this (trimmed) code:**

```
public class HoofdScherm extends Application {
   @FXML
   private ChoiceBox<String> itemKeuze;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage scherm) throws IOException
   {
      // The setup and loading of the FXML file...
   }

   @FXML
   private void initialize()
   {
      // Now I'm only trying to disable the combobox instead of setting the values but the NPE is also thrown
      itemKeuze.setDisable(true);
   }

private void toonItemScherm()
{
    Parent itemScherm = null;

    try {
        itemScherm = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ItemScherm.fxml"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Kon itemScherm niet laden: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    //itemKeuze.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("CD", "Film", "Spel"));
    //itemKeuze.setDisable(true);

    stage = new Stage();
  stage.setTitle("Voeg item toe");
  stage.setResizable(false);
  stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  stage.setScene(new Scene(itemScherm));  
  stage.show();
}
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Isaak/Documents/workspace/JavaPracticumOpdracht3/bin/view/HoofdScherm.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at view.HoofdScherm.start(HoofdScherm.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at view.HoofdScherm.initialize(HoofdScherm.java:109)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the complete stack trace, and include the code where you load the FXML file. Why are you using the same class for your `Application` subclass and for the controller?

Comment: I've added extra code as requested. As for your question. It's just for simplicity because it's a small project for my java course. I did notice now that I'm not using a controller in this FXML class as in the main window file (fx:controller="view.HoofdScherm"). I added this one to this FXML file but it still gave another NPE. Will I need to create separate controllers for every FXML?

Comment: OK, I'm confused now. Are you saying you have more than one FXML file? Which FXML file is the one that defines the `ChoiceBox`? And which are you loading in the `start()` method? And, yes, of course each FXML file should have different controller classes.

Comment: There are two FXML files. This one that gives the problem is a popup window that is shown after a certain button is clicked in the main window. toonItemScherm() loads the pop window. I'm currently separating the code in two controllers

Comment: That doesn't appear to be correct. According to the stack trace, the null pointer exception is thrown from the initialize method (line 109) when an FXMLLoader loads HoofdScherm.fxml in the `start()` method (line 38). The `toonItemScherm` method is not part of the stack trace. Does HoofdScherm.fxml contain the fxml snippet you showed?

Comment: Also, from your previous comment: "It's just for simplicity". How is this simple? You now (I think) have three different instances of your one class created (one for each of the FXML files and one created when you launch the application), all potentially with different fields initialized and different fields still set to null. It's not at all simple to do things this way.

Comment: Sorry, that's because the `itemKeuze.setDisable(true)` is in the `initialize()` method. The `toonItemScherm()` is the code that loads the second FXML file when the `setOnAction()` of a button is triggered in the `initialize()` method. Not HoofdScherm.fxml but ItemScherm.fxml contains the snippet. You have a good point regarding my argument of "simplicity". I had better called it laziness :-)

Comment: So it is obvious to you now why you get the null pointer exception, right?

Comment: You probably mean the same as I posted as an answer? That solved it :-)

Comment: I actually don't understand your answer at all. The point is that HoofdScherm.fxml declares HoofdScherm as its controller but doesn't have an element with `fx:id="itemKeuze"`. So when the `initialize()` method is invoked on the `HoofdScherm` instance created by the FXMLLoader, it cannot inject `itemKeuze`, and so `itemKeuze` is null. Then you get a null pointer exception when you try to invoke a method on it.

Comment: Yes that's right and it's actually the same as what I wrote in the answer. `ItemScherm.fxml` contained the `ChoiceBox` with the `itemKeuze` ID, but it didn't have a controller at first. Now it does: `ItemSchermController.java` (while `HoofdScherm.fxml` uses `HoofdSchermController.java`)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, partially thanks to the points that James_D made.

I didn't add the controller to (the AnchorPane in) the second FXML file `fx:controller=""`. Because no controller was set, no variables (fx:id -> class variables) can be injected. I also created a separate controller for each FXML files because everything was in one main class that extends the Apllication class. That could also have been part of the problem.